# How to combine anchors with ground-truth boxes in region proposal network of a Faster RCNN?

Tags: tensorflow, computer-vision, deep-learning, object-detection

[image: Region Proposal Network of Faster RCNN]

Here is the RPN of a faster RCNN .

We can see a 3*3 sliding window on the final conv feature map . For **each center position in the sliding window** we propose **k anchor boxes** . In order to train this network we should *map these anchor boxes to the real image*.

1. How to map position of the sliding window to position of the real image?
2. How to map proposed regions to the feature map again since sizes won't match each other .

Answer (score -1):

Convolution operation is transformation invariant operation .  Let's say original image is down sampled by **n times** when it comes to the final convolutional layer , Then  to map the center position of above sliding window in to the real image is the task .

I think we can use the transformation invariant quality and **up-sample the feature map by n times** in order to find the location .